# Move from zlib to pigz

Tags: c++, gzip, zlib

Recently I've informed about `pigz` compression tool. After downloading and installing it, the benchmark results have been pretty good.

I have implemented a custom `streambuf` for writing gzipped files (also with ability of `sink` operations).
My question is: is it possible to move from `zlib` to `pigz`, i.e somehow replace zlib functions (`gzwrite`, `gzseek`, `gzopen`...) with equivalent multi-threaded versions from `pigz` in mentioned streambuf implementation? 
Actually I did not find any documentation about how to use `pigz` as a library like `zlib`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

pigz is not a library. You would need to adapt the source code in pigz for use in other applications. That would take some work.

Comment: thanks for the answer. The another option for me was to create a named pipe from my source code, process some data and pass the processed data to pigz command with pipe `std::sytem("pigz -c" + pipeName + ">" + fileName + "&"`... Unfortunately pigz doesn't support non-regular files as input.

Comment: What happens when you try?

Comment: `pigz: skipping: /tmp/tmp.2xiC54 is a special file or device`

Comment: Thank you for the report. I have added a patch for a future version of pigz to permit fifo input files.

Comment: You can use `popen()` instead of `system()` to pipe through a command-line utility in an application.

Comment: Thank you, I'll wait for a new release.